# How to say in German "We'll come tomorrow", e.g. talk at the doctor

Tags: phrase

When I arrange some appointments on the phone and I say "Ich komme morgen bei Ihnen", my colleagues always laugh and find it funny.
How to say it so that it does not sound funny.

Comment: To explain the amused reaction: "Kommen" has in German two meanings: it can mean "come to" (zu jemandem/etwas kommen) or "cum" (bei etwas kommen).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all about prepositions.

The correct answer to "I will come tomorrow" is:

> Ich komme morgen **zu** Ihnen.

The correct answer to your question's title "We'll come tomorrow" is:

> Wir kommen morgen **zu** Ihnen.

What you wrote can be translated as "I will c** tomorrow at your house".